# OpenGl Error after ad loading

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm displaying ads with admob in my app but I get opengl errors every time an ad is loaded. Most of the time it's not a problem, but sometimes it creates a visual glitch on the entire screen.

I'm using a Moto g second gen with lollipop, a friend of mine has the same problem on the Moto g first gen.

This is the code of the error :

```
03-20 03:10:55.061  28273-28273/com.sport.ngn.sport I/Ads﹕ Ad finished loading.
03-20 03:10:55.088  28273-28352/com.sport.ngn.sport E/Adreno-ES20﹕ <check_framebuffer_attachment:854>: Invalid texture format! Returning error!
03-20 03:10:55.088  28273-28352/com.sport.ngn.sport E/Adreno-ES20﹕ <check_framebuffer_object_status:1237>: Framebuffer color attachment incomplete. Returning GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT!
03-20 03:10:55.129  28273-28352/com.sport.ngn.sport E/Adreno-ES20﹕ <check_framebuffer_attachment:854>: Invalid texture format! Returning error!
03-20 03:10:55.129  28273-28352/com.sport.ngn.sport E/Adreno-ES20﹕ <check_framebuffer_object_status:1237>: Framebuffer color attachment incomplete. Returning GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT!
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear: `Invalid texture format! Returning error!`. What texture format are you trying to load?

Comment: I'm only loading ads, i'm doing the exact thing explained in the google dev tutorial for admob. If I disable ads, the error disappear.

Comment: I've got the same problem using Moto G (1st gen) with Android 5.0.2. Any solution?

Comment: Same problem with a very simple webview. No images or anything fancy in the HTML.

Comment: Same problem here... someone did solve it? :S

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the moto g, it can only be fixed by motorola.